# Fetching messages across multiple channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently trying to fetch all messages in a guild, yet the `.fetchMessages` method only works on specific channels.

I've already tried using the `.forEach` function but have received multiple errors whilst doing so.

```
async function intervalFunc() {
  var mainGuild = client.guilds.get("562324876330008576");
  var messagesArray = [];
  await mainGuild.channels.forEach(channel => {
    if (channel.type == "text") {
      channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 20 }).then(msg => {
        messagesArray.push(msg);
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(messagesArray.length)
  //....
}
```

The expected output is at least a few hundred but instead, it outputs `0`.

Comment: You can't await `forEach`, `forEach` function returns undefined

Comment: You should understand how promises work before using async / await, otherwise is a whole mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `await` on the async operation:

```
async function intervalFunc() {
  var mainGuild = client.guilds.get("562324876330008576");
  var messagesArray = [];

  for(channel in mainGuild.channels) {
    if(channel.type == "text") {
      const messages = await channel.fetchMessages({limit: 20});
      messagesArray = [
        ...messagesArray,
        ...messages,
      ];      
    }
  }

  console.log(messagesArray.length);
}
```

So here it will wait for `ferchMessages` to return a value in an asynchronous manner and then proceed to next iteration.

Comment: Please note that by doing so `messagesArray` will contain collections only, not all the messages. If you want it to contain the messages you'll need to replace `messagesArray.push(msg)` with `messagesArray.push(...collection.array())`

Comment: @FedericoGrandi I agree the `messagesArray` will contain nested arrays/collections but we are not solving this problem here. The snippet above indicates the correct usage of `await` and storing the responses asynchronously.

Comment: @Fawaz The code after `forEach()` is called **before** `channel.fetchMessages()` returns anything. Therefore, `messagesArray` will be empty using this code - tested and confirmed. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787).

Comment: @slothiful I get your point, thanks for correcting me. I've updated my solution.